# How to show steps name always in lightning progress indicator?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-progressindicator

When we are using progress indicator only on hover over we can see the step name,but how we need to show the step names always?

Any Ideas!!

I am using  lightning base component "lightning-progress-indicator". Is it possible to achieve using base component?

ThankYou

Comment: Hope you have checked with the LDS [documentation](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-indicator) around this customisation, with help of which you could have additional div in css to show the step name, check if it works for you?

Comment: I am using lightning base component..is it possible to do using that?

Answer (score 0):

With the standard [progress indicator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-progress-indicator/example) it is not possible, you will need to roll out your own implementation using SLDS. You can take the inspiration from [here](https://www.jamessimone.net/blog/joys-of-apex/lwc-custom-path/) if you don't want to start from scratch.